Running gpt4all in vscode with glib2.32 on Ubuntu 20.04 causes OSError
Trying to run llama3.1 with gpt4all on ubuntu 20.04. Constantly facing the given error
OSError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by /home/atmadeep/miniconda3/envs/interpreter-env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gpt4all/llmodel_DO_NOT_MODIFY/build/libllmodel.so)

I have built from source glibc 2.32 (The required version) in my home directory using the instructions here.
I'm trying to run a notebook in vscode, and I'm constantly facing this error as I'm not able to link the newer version. At this point, I'm clueless.

Should I add the path to bin/ directory in LD_PRELOAD and then launch vscode?
Can i set it using LD_LIBRARY_PATH just to run this notebook inside vscode?

